# Can I create new records in Junction object

Tags: junction-object

I have two objects:
1)Projects
2)Consultant
3)Assignment(Junction between Project and Consultant)

Project to Consultant is having many to many relationship defined by Assignment object.

Now my requirement is suppose there is a project named "ABC". How do i create a new Consultant inside the Project page(from the Assignment related list). Now I am only able to see already existing consultants.

Does it require a code?
Can you give me examples of code

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would require code. You can create a Visualforce page to imitate a related list and add that to the page layout for Project, but you'll have to write a moderately substantial amount of both Apex (for the controller) and Visualforce (for the page itself), as well as some configurational things such as a custom button and altering the page layout.

Here is one [example](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Customizing-related-Lists-Using-VisualForce-and-Apex-1327107624263&language=en_US). The difference between your case and this one is that you'll just have to add a button to create a new Consultant record to the page.